Не вызывается событие при отправке формы
При нажатии кнопки "Удалить" не происходит удаление сотрудника по ID, введёному в input type=text. В чём ошибка?
@page "/employee"

@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory

<h3>Сотрудники</h3>

@if (errorMessage != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @errorMessage
    </div>
}
<div class="form_container">
    <form @onsubmit="DeleteEmployee">
        <label>ID сотрудника:</label>
        <input type="text" @bind="id" required> 
        <button type="submit">Удалить</button>
    </form>
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>ФИО</th>
            <th>Дата рождения</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (items == null)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Loading...</td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Birthday.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@code {
    private List<Employee> items;
    private string errorMessage;
    private string id;

    private async Task load()
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("MyAPI");
        try
        {
            items = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Employee>>("api/employee");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = "Не удалось загрузить данные: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await load();
    }
    private async Task DeleteEmployee()
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("MyAPI");    
        if (int.TryParse(id, out int delid))
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await client.DeleteAsync($"api/employee/{delid}");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await load();
                }
                else
                {
                    errorMessage = "Не удалось удалить сотрудника";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = "Не удалось загрузить данные: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Введены некоректные данные";
        }
    }
}


Ну хотя бы найдите уходит ли вызов на бэк. Вы хотите, что бы за вас подебажили?

HTTP Delete запрос не уходит на бэк

Ну проверьте есть что-то в id то в момент парсинга в int? Попробуйте добавить nullable, судя по примерам должно быть так: private string? id; Или присвойте что-то, в других примерах сделано так:  private string id="";

Может дело и не в этом, но для начала я бы попробовал воспроизвести код в точности как в примерах в документации.

Как я понял, метод DeleteEmployee() просто не вызывается. Может я неправильно его пытаюсь вызвать?

Попробуйте поменять <form @onsubmit="DeleteEmployee"> на <EditForm OnSubmit="DeleteEmployee"> ну и закрывающий тег не забудьте поменять тоже.

Попробовал, уже функция вызывается но значению id не присваивается значение, уверен что я просто неправильно делаю из-за отсутствия опыта
